# Google Map not loading when formed in HTML

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-maps

When I load up my code on Android it gives me a blank screen, and when I load it in firefox I get "Map Created" with no errors in the console.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <title>HD testapp</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!--Link to CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style_ride.css">
    <!--Link to Javascript file
    <script src="js.js"></script>-->

    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

    <script>

        function initGeolocation() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallBack, errorCallBack);
            } else {
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "Geolocation failed";
            }
        }

        function errorCallBack() {
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "Map failed";
        }

        function successCallBack(position) {
            var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "Coordinates initialized";
            var map_options = {
                zoom: 15,
                center: myLatLng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "Map options created";
            map_container = document.getElementById('map');
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "Map container created";
            var map = new google.maps.Map(map_container, map_options);
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "Map created";
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body onload="javascript:initGeolocation()">

<div id=map" style="height:100%; width:100%;"></div>

<p id="status"></p>

</body>
```

Here's the HTML code, I've been driving myself crazy trying to figure out what's going wrong.  MY end goal is to get a map that follows you, but getting it to show up is the first step!

P.S. The linked CSS only center aligns the debugging text.

```
/*Whole page classes*/
body {
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: i'm sorry, did you have a question?

Comment: is it totally blank or is it the grey map with the google logo on the bottom but without the map itself?

Comment: It is completely blank on android, no grey map or anything.  On PC it is also completely blank, bar the debugging text I put in.